# How to detect active window of multiple instances when back button pressed in Xamarin.Forms WebView OnBackButtonPressed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've wrapped a webpage and the app can display multiple instances of mainpage (webwiew) activity. When hardware back button pressed OnBackButtonPressed() method is triggered with no args. And it's triggered multiple times (as much as instances count).

[image]

Currently all visible and invisible webpages go back if they can, or visible window disappears if any of them cannot go back.

I need to bypass invisible instances and go back if needed on visible webview. How can I do that?

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        var isActiveAndVisible = SomeMagicalCode();

        if (isActiveAndVisible && webView.CanGoBack )
        {
            webView.GoBack();
        }

        return base.OnBackButtonPressed() || (isActiveAndVisible && webView.CanGoBack);
    }
```

Comment: **I've wrapped a webpage and the app can display multiple instances of mainpage (webwiew) activity.** I don't quite understand  the meaning  of this sentence, how do you do?

Comment: If you click links from website (ie in mail), a new instance will be created as shown in screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I've used WebView.ClassId as fingerprint; that was my workaround.

I've created an app wide static variable to track active visible instance:

```
public static class Settings
{
   public static string ActiveInstanceId = "";
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public string InstanceId = "";

public App()
{
    InstanceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    Settings.ActiveInstanceId = InstanceId;
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    if(Settings.ActiveInstanceId == InstanceId)
    {
        Settings.ActiveInstanceId = "";
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
   WebView.ClassId = ((App)(App.Current)).InstanceId;
}


protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (Settings.ActiveInstanceId == WebView.ClassId)
    {
        if (WebView.CanGoBack)
        {
            WebView.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return base.OnBackButtonPressed(); 
}
```

Comment: This won't work if active webview is not processed on last fire.